# Get a listing of files in a folder and move them to 4 subfolders using ForEach & Switch

Tags: powershell, foreach, switch-statement

Say I have an command that grabs 4 filenames from a folder called `Copy` to an array:

```
$Files2 = Get-ChildItem "Copy" -File
```

In my current directory, there are 2 folders `Copy` and `Work` (containing the 4 folders `Labs, Assignments, Lectures, Scripts`).

My goal is to move the 4 files from `Copy` to their corresponding 4 folders with the matching names. For example, file `Lab12` would go into folder `Labs`. I run into an error with my script because it can't figure out where to place the files without changing directories.

```
$Files2 = Get-ChildItem "Copy" -File

Foreach ($i in $Files2) {
    Switch -Wildcard ($i) {
        ("*lec*") {Move-Item $_ -Destination "Lectures"}
        ("*lab*") {Move-Item $_ -Destination "Labs"}
        ("*assign*") {Move-Item $_ -Destination "Assignments"}
        ("*.ps1*") {Move-Item $_ -Destination "Scripts"}
    }        
    $Count = $Count + 1
}
```

If I add `Set-Location Work` before the loop, it works as intended. Where I am going wrong with this? I understand that it's trying to look for the files in my current directory, but I'm stumped trying to figure out other possibilities I haven't tried yet. I have not learned `hashtables` yet, so I'm using `switches` instead.

Edit:

I should have also said that I tried putting `-Destination "Work\Lectures"` inside my `Switch` statements, but that didn't work either.

Comment: You're using the pipeline variable **$_** but you don't have a pipeline. ;-)

Comment: Doesn't `$_` refer to the current item of the array that's being tested? Even so, the code should still execute but it doesn't. For this script, `$i` and `$_` should be interchangeable. Here's a sample error from the console: `Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Work\Lab12.txt' because it does not exist.`

Comment: You use $i  in your loop declaration not $_. If you're not sure you could use a write-verbose to output what's in your variables or just for testing a write-host.

Comment: You might use full paths instead of relative ones?

Comment: So I switched all `$_` to `$i`, and I gave all `Switch` arguments an absolute pathname of (depending on folder name) `"C:\Users\Work\Lectures"`, but it does not work. The error is: `Move-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\users\Lab12.txt' because it does not exist.`

Comment: Notice how it says `C:\Users\Lab12.txt`... My current directory is `C:\Users` but I don't understand why it won't go into the `Work` directory even with an absolute pathname.

Comment: Using your originally posted code in the question change `$_` to `$_.FullName` and change the destinations to relative paths such as `".\Work\Lectures"`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician It worked, thank you so much!!! Please post this as an answer so I can mark it as solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite what Olaf suggests, you can indeed use `$_` because `Switch` will iterate through an array, and `$_` represents the current item in the array. You will need to either specify the `FullName` property of the item, or pipe `$_` to `Move-Item`. You also need to provide a valid relative path. This works (tested on my machine):

```
$Files2 = Get-ChildItem "Copy" -File

Switch -Wildcard ($Files2) {
    ("*lec*") {Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination ".\Work\Lectures"}
    ("*lab*") {Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination ".\Work\Labs"}
    ("*assign*") {Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination ".\Work\Assignments"}
    ("*.ps1*") {Move-Item $_.FullName -Destination ".\Work\Scripts"}
}
```